# Function to check if string length in greater than or less than required amount

Tags: php, strlen

I want to create a function to check if the length of a string is greater than or less than a required amount:

Something like this:

```
function check_string_lenght($string, $min, $max)
{
 if ($string == "")
 {
   return x;   
 }
 elseif (strlen($string) > $max)
 {
   return y;
 } 
 elseif (strlen($string) < $min)
 {
   return z;
 }
 else
 {
   return $string;
 }

}
```

The problem is I don't know what to return. I don't want to return something like 'String is too short'. Maybe a number, `0` `if == ""`, `1` if greater than, `2` if less than?

What would be the proper way of doing this?

Comment: No [mcve].  We cannot know what a correct answer looks like if you don't definitively declare it in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return `1`, `0` and `-1` like a lot of comparison functions do. In this case the return values could have these meanings:

- `0`: The string length is inside the bounds
- `-1`: too short
- `1`: too long

I don't think there is *a proper way* for this. You just have to document and explain the return values.

Comment: @johnathanross: What do you mean? An empty string is too short as its length is `0`.

Answer (score 5):

I would have the function return a boolean value, where `TRUE` would mean that the string is within limits and `FALSE` would mean that the string length is invalid and change the part of code where the function is used.

Furthermore, I would redesign the function as following:

```
function is_string_length_correct( $string, $min, $max ) {

    $l = mb_strlen($string);
    return ($l >= $min && $l <= $max);
}
```

The part of code where the function is used could look like this:

```
if (!is_string_length_correct($string, $min, $max)) {
    echo "Your string must be at least $min characters long at at 
        most $max characters long";
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the length is lower than required then return 0 if more than required then -1 if within range then 1

```
function check_string_lenght($string, $min, $max)
{
 if (strlen($string)<$min)
   return 0;   
 elseif (strlen($string) > $max)
   return -1;
 else
   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkWord_len($string, $nr_limit) {
    $text_words = explode(" ", $string);
    $text_count = count($text_words);
    for ($i=0; $i < $text_count; $i++){ //Get the array words from text
        // echo $text_words[$i] ; "
        //Get the array words from text
        $cc = (strlen($text_words[$i])) ;//Get the lenght char of each words from array
        if($cc > $nr_limit) //Check the limit
        {
            $d = "0" ;
        }
    }
    return $d ; //Return the value or null
}

$string_to_check = " heare is your text to check"; //Text to check
$nr_string_limit = '5' ; //Value of limit len word
$rez_fin = checkWord_len($string_to_check,$nr_string_limit) ;

if($rez_fin =='0')
{
    echo "false";
    //Execute the false code
}
elseif($rez_fin == null)
{
    echo "true";
    //Execute the true code
}
```